# How to get an part of string which matches an List() result?

Tags: string, vb.net, list

So, here's the code. What am I trying to do is to get the `str` variable, check if it contains an entry of `strList` and if it does return that entry (so I can use it in IF statements etc etc). Oh, and yes, I need to use variable names in the `List()`. So how cloud I get that?

```
Dim strList As New List(Of String)
Dim str As String = "SomeFancyStringThere"
strList.Add(somefancystringname, "Fancy")
```

What have I tried:

```
Dim strList As New List(Of String)
Dim str As String = "SomeFancyStringThere"
strList.Add(somefancystringname, "Fancy")
If str.Contains(strList.Any) Then
  Dim strFound As String = strList. 'and I am completely stuck there.
End If
```

Thanks in advance,
DDev.

Comment: `Oh, and yes, I need to use variable names in the List()`  What does that even mean?  Surely you have taken notice that the IDE indicates a problem with `strList.Add(somefancystringname, "Fancy")` ?

Comment: I does not indicate a problem at all for me.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do here. If strList is really a List, then use Contains function. BUT it looks like that you want to use a dictionary, because of the two parameters of the Add function in your code (which does not compile). In this case use the TryGetValue function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand of your want is that u are trying to filter a list of string.Or in simple words,you are trying to find out if your `List(Of String` contains a specific string, right ?? Well, here's the most easiest solution for that :

```
Private MylistOfString As New List(Of String)
 Private Function CheckIfExists(byval myStr as string) As String
 For each item As String in MylistOfString
   If item = myStr Then
     Return myStr
   End if
 Next
 Return ""
End Function
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: please turn on Option Strict for all your code. Your Function has no datatype. Your function does not return a value on all code paths.

Comment: Mary,is it ok now ?

Comment: I edited per your request. My edit will show up after peer review.

Comment: mary,in ur suggested edit u add `Return ""` , why ?? It is already returning `myStr` isnt it enough ?

Comment: mary ?? Why is it required to return `""` ??? the code works perfect without it :)

Comment: All code paths need a return value. If nothing matches then what will your call get back?

Comment: owww....Totally missed that, i assumed that the **Bad Word** would always exists !!!!! Thnx bro :)

Comment: Trying it out now.

Comment: did it work ? If it did, make sure to mark it as answer if it helped :)